# Store logged in users to cloud Firestore in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

In my flutter app users log in using their phone. so how can I store the users id in cloud firestore and save the account for when the user log in again and keep their detail? (I used shared preferences to check if the user has logged)

Here is my code if necessary.

```
import 'package:country_code_picker/country_code_picker.dart';
import 'package:demo/Firebase/auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

import 'BottomBarPages/home.dart';

class SignIn extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SignInState createState() => _SignInState();
}

class _SignInState extends State<SignIn> {
  TextEditingController phoneController = new TextEditingController();
  String phoneNumber = "";

  SharedPreferences logindata;
  bool newuser;

  bool shower = false;
  String smsCode;
  String verificationCode;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    check_if_already_login();
  }
  void check_if_already_login() async {
    logindata = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    newuser = (logindata.getBool('login') ?? true);
    print(newuser);
    if (newuser == false) {
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home()));
    }
  }
  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Clean up the controller when the widget is disposed.
    phoneController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _onCountryChange(CountryCode countryCode) {
    this.phoneNumber = countryCode.toString();
    print("New Country selected: " + countryCode.toString());
  }

  void check() {
    final myPhone = this.phoneNumber + phoneController.text;
    print("Full Text: " + myPhone);
  }
  Future<void> man() async{

  }
  Future<void> submit() async {
    final myPhone = this.phoneNumber + phoneController.text;
    final PhoneVerificationCompleted verificationCompleted =
        (AuthCredential credential) {

    };


    final PhoneVerificationFailed verificationFailed =
        (AuthException exception) {};

    final PhoneCodeSent phoneCodeSent = (String verId, [int forceCodeResend]) {
      this.verificationCode = verId;
      smsCodeDialog(context).then((value) => print("signed"));
    };

    final PhoneCodeAutoRetrievalTimeout autoRetrievalTimeout = (String verId) {
      this.verificationCode = verId;
    };
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: myPhone,
        timeout: const Duration(seconds: 5),
        verificationCompleted: verificationCompleted,
        verificationFailed: verificationFailed,
        codeSent: phoneCodeSent,
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: autoRetrievalTimeout);
  }

  Future<bool> smsCodeDialog(BuildContext context) {
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: false,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text(
              'Enter Code',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.lightGreen, fontSize: 24),
            ),
            content: TextField(
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              onChanged: (Value) {
                smsCode = Value;
              },
            ),
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            actions: [
              FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    String phone = phoneController.text;
                    if (phone != '') {
                      print('Successfull');
                      logindata.setBool('login', false);
                      logindata.setString('username', phone);
                      Navigator.push(context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home()));
                    }
                    else{
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      signIn();
                    }
                    // FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((user) {
                    //   if (user != null) {
                    //     Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    //     Navigator.push(context,
                    //         MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home()));
                    //   } else {
                    //     Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    //     signIn();
                    //   }
                    // });
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    'Verify',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.lightGreen),
                  ))
            ],
          );
        });
    // CircularProgressIndicator(
    //   valueColor: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.lightGreen),
    //   value: 0.25,
    // );

  }

  signIn() {
    AuthCredential phoneAuthCredential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
        verificationId: verificationCode, smsCode: smsCode);
    FirebaseAuth.instance
        .signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential)
        .then((user) => Navigator.push(
            context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home())))
        .catchError((e) => print(e));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);

        if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
          currentFocus.unfocus();
        }
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                    begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                    end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                    stops: [0.1, 0.3, 1.0],
                    colors: [
                      Colors.lightGreen[300],
                      Colors.white,
                      Colors.lightGreen[50]
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 150,
                        child: Image.asset('images/phone.png'),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 20,
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                              border: Border.all(color: Colors.lightGreen)),
                          width: double.infinity,
                          height: 40,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30),
                            child: Row(
                             // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: [
                                CountryCodePicker(
                                  dialogTextStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                                  onChanged: _onCountryChange,
                                  initialSelection: 'US',
                                  favorite: ['+251', 'ET'],
                                ),
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                                  child: SizedBox(
                                    width: 150,
                                    child: TextFormField(
                                      controller: phoneController,
                                      keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                                        border: InputBorder.none,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 20,
                      ),
                      MaterialButton(
                        onPressed: submit,
                        minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 80,
                        height: 45,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                        color: Colors.lightGreen,
                        splashColor: Colors.green,
                        child: Text(
                          "Confirm",
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding:
                            EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 14, horizontal: 64),
                        child: Text(
                          "you'll receive a 6 digit code click Confirm to verify",
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 22,
                            color: Colors.lightGreen,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

help me on how to store the user info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used the phone number login, but I usually do in this way:

First of all I let the user LogIn, then I get their uid. It should be provided with the User object you get after login.

Inside Firestore, I have previously created a collection "UserData".

When I got the uid of the user, I check if there is already a doc inside "UserData".

If not, then I proceed by creating the doc and saving the user info.

If the doc is already there, I read the user info.

EDIT:

Here's all the documentation regarding the SignIn methods: [Here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/overview/)

Once the user is logged in, you have to work with Firestore, in order to store the user information you have somehow collected.

Here's Firestore documentation: [Here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/overview)

Now you need to understand if it is the first time the user logs in. That's up to you.
When you've got this information:

If it is the first time the user logs in I would directly add the information to the DB. Here's an example (do not copy and paste this code directly, becouse as I said, the flow depends a lot from your app code).

```
 CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

 users.add({
       'full_name': fullName, // John Doe
       'company': company, // Stokes and Sons
       'age': age // 42
     })
     .then((value) => print("User Added"))
     .catchError((error) => print("Failed to add user: $error"));
```

Now, every time an "old" user logs in, I would just retrive the data with a get:

```
CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

users.doc(documentId).get()
```

Comment: That could be a lot of code and depends a lot from your application. I'll add some details and links to documentation you could use.